# Properly running mutations for a dynamic list of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, react-18

My use case is that given a user input that's an array of files, the application initiates upload for all files in parallel, and shows a component for each upload in progress. I've attempted to use the `useMutation` hook from `@tanstack/react-query` to do this, and because you can't have an array of hooks, I did something like this:

```js
async function uploadFile(file) { ... }

// Supposed to start the file upload on mount.
function UploadingFile({file, ...}) {
  const { mutate } = useMutation(() => uploadFile(file), ...);

  // This doesn't work in React strict/concurrent mode
  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, [mutate]);
}

function UploadingFileList({files, ...}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {files.map((file, index) => (
        <UploadingFile key={index} file={file} />
      )};
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `useEffect` fires twice in React strict/concurrent mode (and I understand why that happens). I've considered 2 potential solutions:

1. Implement some hack that makes `useEffect` fire only once. There are plenty of examples around using for example `useRef`. The problem with this approach is that it's a hack.
2. Use `useQuery`/`useQueries` instead of `useMutation`, which fires automatically already. The problem with this approach is that it needs a query key but a file upload operation doesn't have an inherently unique key. A way around this is to perhaps use a randomly generated ID for each file upload.

Both of these approaches seem hacky so I'd like a second opinion. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the useEffect hook with an empty array as the second argument, which will cause the effect to run only once.

Ex of how you can use the useEffect hook to start the file upload process in the UploadingFile component:

```
function UploadingFile({file, ...}) {
  const { mutate } = useMutation(() => uploadFile(file), ...);

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, []);  // This will cause the effect to run only once
}
```

Or, you can use the useMutation hook inside the UploadingFile component to create a function that starts the file upload process, and then call this function from the UploadingFile component's render method:

```
function UploadingFile({file, ...}) {
  const [mutate, { isLoading, isError }] = useMutation(() => uploadFile(file), ...);

  const startUpload = () => {
    mutate();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? 'Uploading...' : 'Ready to upload'}
      {isError && 'An error occurred'}
      <button onClick={startUpload}>Start upload</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This approach will not have the same issue with the useEffect hook firing multiple times in strict/concurrent mode, because the mutate function is not being called from inside an effect.

Comment: `mutate` is stable across renders so it's no different than using an empty array. The issue is that React strict mode in dev intentionally (and in the future concurrent mode might as well) mounts the component twice, causing even an `useEffect` with empty array to fire twice. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502

Comment: I want to avoid the button approach as well because the file-selection operation should already initiate the upload (think Gmail attachment upload behavior).

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is to *not* fire the mutation in `useEffect`, but in the event handler that triggers the file upload by the user.

You can certainly call `mutate` multiple times in a row, or you can have one mutation that just fires multiple calls with `Promise.all()`

Let's assume the event handler is a click that receives an array of things:

```
const { mutate } = useMutation({
  mutationFn: files => {
    return Promise.all(files.map(uploadFile))
  }
})

<MyUploadComponent 
  onClick={(files) => mutate(files)}
/>
```